# Return rows that have the equal values in a column but a different value in another column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return results that match this criteria

- Same `ProfileType` with 2 DIFFERENT `ColorCode`

My current query returns all ProfileTypes and ColorCodes

```
ProfileType | ColorCode

SPT1        | 8XYZ
SPT1        | 1XYZ
SPT2        | 4XYZ
SPT2        | 4XYZ
SPT3        | 4XYZ
SPT3        | 9XYZ
SPT4        | 4XYZ
SPT4        | 4XYZ
```

I would only like to return these rows from the above result set because they are the same ProfileType but with two different ColorCodes

```
ProfileType | ColorCode
SPT1        | 8XYZ
SPT1        | 1XYZ
SPT3        | 4XYZ
SPT3        | 9XYZ
```

Query

```
SELECT. P.ProfileType, E.ColorCode,
FROM profilegroups AS PG
 INNER JOIN mfg.profiles AS P
         ON PG.id = P.pickgroup
 INNER JOIN exts AS E
         ON E.Profile = P.Profile
        AND E.ProductNumber IN ('XYZ123', 'MX231X')
        AND PG.DoProcess = 1 
        AND P.ProfileType IN ('SPT1','SPT2','SPT3','SPT4','SPTX2','SPT31', 'SPT90');
```

Tables

```
ProfileGroups
    - id
Profiles 
    - Profile 
    - ProfileType 
    - PickGroup
Exts
    - Profile 
    - ColorCode
```

Profiles and Exts have a primary key Profile which is DIFFERENT from ProfileType which comes from the Profiles table

Comment: I feel like you're nearly there

Comment: Did you forgot to include SPT4 in your expected result?

Comment: @DanielBlasis Typo. They should be the same color. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Join with a subquery that gets the number of different color codes for each profile type, but only returns the ones with more that one color code:

```
SELECT profileType
FROM Exts
GROUP BY profileType
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colorCode) > 1
```

The full query would then look like:

```
SELECT. ProfileType, Color,
FROM profilegroups AS PG
 INNER JOIN mfg.profiles AS P
         ON PG.id = P.pickgroup
 INNER JOIN exts AS E
         ON E.ProfileType = P.ProfileType
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT profile
    FROM Exts
    GROUP BY profile
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colorCode) > 1) M 
        ON M.profile = P.profile
WHERE   E.ProductNumber IN ('XYZ123', 'MX231X')
        AND PG.DoProcess = 1 
        AND P.ProfileType IN ('SPT1','SPT2','SPT3','SPT4','SPTX2','SPT31', 'SPT90')
```

Comment: This wont work I have updated the OP with table definitions and changed the query to show which tables each column is from

Comment: @ghan the logic remains the same.

Comment: profiletype comes from the profiles table. profile (which is different than profiletype) comes from the exts table so the subquery wont work. I think I would have to rejoin all the tables again?

Comment: OK, I think I might have fixed it. It would help if you showed a sample of the input, not just the result. It thought the table at the top was the one with all the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select profileType, colorCode
from (select distinct profileType, colorCode from table) a
group by profileType
having count(*) > 1;
```